# Slow frame rate when playing video in Pygame

Tags: python, video

I've been doing some project on playing the videos and could use the button to change the movies selection. I ended up using pygame but the things are when the video has the resolution more than 320x240, the movie is really lag and sound comes after the frame. Anyone have any opinions, I'm kinda super beginner to Rasp as well as Python language.
Really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't know much about this but I'd think it would vary depending on video/sound encoding, if you use hardware decoding and the RAM split for GPU/CPU. Do you know if the 320x240 video uses 100% CPU?

Comment: It is about the pygame library. though i tried some ways to use the hardware acceleration abut it seems that the video is only encoded by the the pygame.

Comment: I can't really be much help then as I know nothing about pygame. I suggest you check your memory split and try 128MB for the GPU. The easiest way to set it is with `sudo raspi-config`.